# How to keep a persistent connection to my mongo instance with express router

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connection, router

I have a express router such as:

```
var express = require('express')
, router = express.Router()
, bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, mongoclient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, dbconfig = require('../assets/config.db.json');

router.use( bodyParser.json() );
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

router.post('/api/search', (req, res, next) => {
  var term = req.body.searchTerm;
  mongoclient.connect(dbconfig.url, (err, db) => {
    db.accessDatabase(term, (err, result) => {
      db.close();
      if (err) res.json({result: err});
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have have read that if there is a lot of overhead to make a connection to my db each REST call then I need to make a persistent connection for someone using this REST API. What is the proper way to do this within my router? Right now each time a post request is received it will open a connection, access the db and then close the connection.

EDIT: for clarity I used db.accessDatabase(), but this is not the actual syntax being used within my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You open do MongoClient.connect once when your app boots up and reuse the db object. It's not a singleton connection pool each .connect creates a new connection pool.

From [node-mongodb-native](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-mongodb-native/mSGnnuG8C1o/Hiaqvdu1bWoJ)

Personally, i do it like this

```
var params = {/*config, etc... required to bootstrap models */}
require('./app/models')(params)
    .then(afterModels)
    .then(startServer)

function afterModels(theModels) {
    params.models = theModels
    let providers = require('./app/providers')(params)
    params.providers = providers
    // boot strap routes
    require('./app/routes')(params)

    // controllers can use params which has models (db object,e tc.. inside)
}

function startServer() {}
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the proper way of doing this within my router? connect on the first REST call and each subsequent REST call would check to see if the db object is connected?

Comment: @httpNick connect on app boots up and share it across the app. personally, i bootstrap the app by acquiring all necessary resources (database, etc...) and share it across the route controllers.

Comment: Hmm, so from the entry file I use (I call it server.js) I want to connect, and somehow send the db object to my router? How do I share this db object to my router?

Comment: @httpNick i updated my answer to include my way of doing it.